# Django DateField increment

Tags: django

The task is to display Personal and Pensionar today birth day in one template and to have a hiperlink to display the case of tomorrow birth day.

Of course yesterday option will be the opposite from tomorrow.

In case of current date it works perfect but I do not know how to increase the date variable, then transmit to view.

model.py

```
class Personal(models.Model):
    nume = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    prenume = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    dataNastere = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nume

class Pensionar(models.Model):
    nume = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    prenume = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    dataNastere = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nume
```

url.py

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^omagiatulZilei/$', views.omagiatulZilei_list, name='omagiatulZilei_list'),
    url(r'^omagiatulZilei_next/$', views.nextDate, name='nextDate'),
```

]

views.py

```
def omagiatulZilei_list(request):
    today = timezone.now().date()
    personals = Personal.objects.order_by('nume').filter(
        dataNastere__month=today.month,
        dataNastere__day=today.day)

    pensionars = Pensionar.objects.order_by('nume').filter(
        dataNastere__month=today.month,
        dataNastere__day=today.day)

    context = {'personals' : personals, 'pensionars' : pensionars}
    return render(request, 'blog/omagiatulZilei_list.html', context=context)

def nextDate(request, ??):  # ?? is a datefield variable
    nextD = ?? + 1          # increment by 1 (the meaning is next day)

    personals = Personal.objects.order_by('nume').filter(
        dataNastere__month=nextD.month,
        dataNastere__day=nextD.day)

    pensionars = Pensionar.objects.order_by('nume').filter(
        dataNastere__month=nextD.month,
        dataNastere__day=nextD.day)

    context = {'personals' : personals, 'pensionars' : pensionars}
    return render(request, 'blog/omagiatulZilei_list.html', context=context)
```

omagiatulZilei_list.html

```
{% load staticfiles %}

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Omagiatul Zilei</title>
    </head>
<body>

<a href="{% url 'nextDate' %}">next date</a><br>

{% for personal in personals %}
    {{ personal.nume }} 
    {{ personal.prenume }},
    {{ personal.dataNastere }} <br>
{% endfor %}

{% for pensionar in pensionars %}
    {{ pensionar.nume }}
    {{ pensionar.prenume }}, 
    {{ pensionar.dataNastere }} <br>
{% endfor %}

</body>
</html>
```

Tell me the correct answer in code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something like this?

```
today = timezone.now().date()              # gets today
nextD = today + datetime.timedelta(days=1) # adds one day to today
```